# Получаю от телеграмм бота иероглифы вместо русских символов из JSON

Tags: python, ubuntu, telebot

Пока бот хостился на моём ПК на винде всё было нормально но когда я закинул его на виртуальный сервер на ubuntu 18.04 то из базы данных которая хранится в JSON файле я получаю какую то чушь хотя я через файлзиллу проверил базу и там всё нормально и русский текст который прописан в самом коде, бот пишет нормально но вот символы из файла преобразуются в каракули вот такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что-то с кодировкой, попробуйте указать кодировку в начале кода `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Под windows файл через open по умолчанию открывается в кодировке cp1251. На других системах может использоваться другая кодировка. Чтобы работало на других системах так же как на windows, нужно указывать кодировку принудительно через параметр encoding функции open. А вообще, в вопросе нужно приводить код, который вы запускаете.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, принудительное указание `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` в исходнике нужно только для Python2. В любом случае, если бы была проблема в этом, была бы ошибка при запуске файла, а не неправильное отображение.

Comment: @insolor да, Вы правы, была бы другая ошибка) не видя код сложно что-то предполагать, кроме того что проблема с кодировкой